# How to get sphinx connection failed error in php

Tags: php, error-handling, sphinx

this is my code:

```
    include_once( "extensions/sphinxapi.php" );
    $mode = SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2;
    $host = "localhostt"; //am giving wrong to get error
    $port = 9312;
    $ranker = SPH_RANK_NONE;
    $ranker = SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25;

    $cl = new SphinxClient();
    $cl->GetLastError();    //this line is Not working
    $testcon=$cl->SetServer ( $host, $port );
    if($testcon){ print_r($cl); }else if(!($testcon)) {echo "show error";}
    $cl->SetConnectTimeout ( 1 );
    $cl->SetArrayResult ( true );
    $cl->SetWeights ( array ( 100,50,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100));
    $cl->SetMatchMode ( $mode );
    $cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, $sortby);
    $cl->SetRankingMode ($ranker);
    $cl->ResetFilters();
```

sphinx working properly. that is not a problem. but if i give the host name with wrong name means it doesnot show any error.

```
$host = "localhostt";//like this
$c1->GetLastError(); //not working Gives empty result .
$c1->GetLastWarning(); //not working also gives empty result.
```

how can i get the connection failed error. i need to show the error in my site.Thanks.

Comment: The SphinxClient class doesnt actully TRY connecting to searchd, until you run one of the actual communication functions (RunQuery/RunQueries/Status etc). So GetLastError will ONLY be populated after running one of those functions. Can use IsConnectError to distinguish the type of error.

Comment: You are Exactly correct.after running
$search = $cl->Query($keywords, $indexName); only is shows error.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$connected = $cl->Open();
```

It returns **false** when connect failed.

For example:

```
  $this->sphinxApiClient = new \SphinxClient();
  $this->sphinxApiClient->SetConnectTimeout(self::CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
  $this->sphinxApiClient->SetMaxQueryTime(self::MAX_QUERY_TIME);
  $this->sphinxApiClient->SetServer($host, $port);
  $connected =  $this->sphinxApiClient->Open();

 if (!$connected) {
    ....
 } else {
    ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Sphinx, but I think localhost will be used as fallback.

The most simple solution is to stop the Sphinx daemon and try to connect again.

But, this is better:

```
try
{
    // connect to Sphinx
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   // handle the error customized!
}
```

Comment: Yes, but with try/catch you can simulate it easy with your own error handling.

Comment: you are right. it did not come to catch block. only it shows blank page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //  after running the query only it shows error

$search = $cl->Query($keywords, $indexName); 

   if ( $search===false )
     {
        print_r($cl->GetLastError());
     }
```

Thanks for the help.